# Start and Back Button pressed in rapid succession WP7

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

I asked this question in a similar post but there have been significant updates since then, but still no results so I will try to re-ask the question with the updated information.

Basically I have a pivot view with 4 pivot items. If I create the scenario where I hit the windows key then rapidly press the back key my application will reopen without reconstructing (this is the expected outcome). The functionality of the application is there. I can press application bar buttons etc.

What doesn't work is the pivot items are frozen. If I was on Pivot item A and I press the start and back button quickly I come back to Pivot Item A. If I try to switch Pivot Items, the screen does not update, its "frozen" on Pivot Item A BUT the functionality of Pivot Item B is there. (I know this because the application bar Icons for Pivot Item B are now showing).

I have read many articles on proper tombstoning scenarios and how to approach this problem. My data IS being tombstoned correctly, and upon reactivation the tombstoned data works. No objects are null so I don't have any exceptions being thrown at me.

I check to see if I need to reload the Main ViewModel (I don't need to in this case so the UI elements being created initially are not being re created).

What does fix the problem however is if the application is reconstructed. Lets say I go to the marketplace from my app, let it finish loading and press back, My application will be refreshed and working fine since it properly deactivated and reconstructed istelf. I don't rely on constructors doing all the work so I am not missing any key elements not being set when they aren't fired in the windows/back button scenario.

Does anyone have any idea why my screen would not be updating?

constructor/loaded event/on navigated to event

```
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(MainPage_Loaded);
    }
    private void MainPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (App.firstTimeLoading == true)
        {
            App.firstTimeLoading = false;
        }
        BuildApplicationBar();
    }

     protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
      this.DataContext = App.ViewModel;
        App.viewIdentifier = StringResource.MainPageView;

        if (!App.ViewModel.IsDataLoaded)
        {
            App.ViewModel.LoadData();                

            String bookTitle;
            App.Parser.appBookInfoDict.TryGetValue(CPlayerInventoryKeys.kInventoryKeyTitleShortTitle, out bookTitle);
            PivotBackground.Title = bookTitle.ToUpper();

            CreatePivotItems();
        }
        if (App.playerController.chapterPlayer.Source == null)
            App.restoreStateClass.RestoreState();

        //applies the proper background image
        if (App.isDarkTheme)
        {
            BitmapImage bitmapImage = new BitmapImage(new Uri(StringResource.PanoramaBlackImage, UriKind.Relative));
            BackgroundImage.ImageSource = bitmapImage;
            BackgroundImage.Opacity = .85;
        }
        else
        {
            BitmapImage bitmapImage = new BitmapImage(new Uri(StringResource.PanoramaWhiteImage, UriKind.Relative));
            BackgroundImage.ImageSource = bitmapImage;
            BackgroundImage.Opacity = .5;
        }

        if (App.firstTimeLoading == false && PivotBackground.SelectedItem != SuggestedPivotItem)
            BuildApplicationBar();
        else if (PivotBackground.SelectedItem == SuggestedPivotItem)
        {
            BuildMarketPlaceApplicationBar();
        }
        base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
    }
```

Comment: Have you got a complete repro you can share?

Comment: I updated with some relavent code, still step by step debugging this though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. Since I had a media element open (play/paused) and I was implementing the "non tombstoned" method of hitting windows key and back button very quickly, the media element source was corrupt. Even though I reset this source, apparently it can be ignored and not function properly. All I had to do was add a line of code to the Application Deactivated handler.

```
    private void Application_Deactivated(object sender, DeactivatedEventArgs e)
    {
        App.MainAudioPlayer.Source = null; //(only showing line added)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The behavior you are describing seems to be solely related to the way you are manipulating data internally and constructing your layout. I tested this both in the emulator and on a couple of physical devices, both producing normal output (even when bound to a view model).

Try creating a new Pivot-based application (without all your data - just using the default template) and see if the problem persists. Also worth mentioning - are you testing on a device or in the emulator?

Comment: Ill be trying some of the things we talked about last night. I do remember however even commenting out all of my view model bindings for the main page and the problem still persisted.

Comment: Interesting, I have fixed the problem for one of my views which is good news! The weird part is for the main view. In the OnNavigatedTo Event I set a this.Loaded event and after it runs all the other functionality, it never hits the loaded event for the main view.

Comment: Is the Loaded event actually wired?

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by that? I set the loaded event to a new event in the OnNavigatedTo so that is set properly, it never hits it though

Comment: I think there is something wrong with the way you are setting it. The `Loaded` event should generally be set in the page constructor. Try moving it outside `OnNavigatedTo` and put it right after `InitializeComponent();`

Comment: but if it never hits the constructor in the case of windows button back button really fast it wouldn't be called anyways

Comment: You don't need the constructor to be hit by code other than at initialization. All you need is a correctly wired `Loaded` event.

Comment: Unfortunately, it is still not calling the loaded event

Comment: Update your post with the init code (the constructor + Loaded & OnNavigatedTo).

Comment: Interesting find.... Lets say the user did the windows key back button from a different view (other than the main page view). So, they go back into the app on this Different View. If they hit the back button in this view (which should go back to the main page view) it calles the main page view OnNavigatedTo the DifferentViewLoadedEvent then the MainPage LoadedEvent.... after this has all fired the screen is in its "frozen state"

Comment: Mind hosting the entire solution somewhere? With the multitude of code you are invoking, the problem can be anywhere.

Comment: unfortunately I can't. Since this is a project for the company I am working for. Is there any reason I would need to save the page state in the PhoneApplicationService.Current.State and reload it from there?

Comment: It is useful if you are downloading data from online sources, for example, and don't want to re-download it later. You can either use the state or Isolated Storage to save existing objects. Basically, `PhoneApplicationService` has the plumbing done for you when it comes to storing complex objects.

Comment: Last night you said you made an app that tested this functionality and everything worked fine. Is there somewhere I can view this just to see if I am setting up/linking everything properly. Since I have commented out everything from the UI I believe it doesn't have to do with that but rather my startup cycle.

Comment: I have one suspicion - sometimes working with the `ApplicationBar` directly can cause performance lags. Remove all app bar building method calls from the loading events. Also, merge `Loaded` and `OnNavigatedTo` in a single event - `OnNavigatedTo`.

Comment: I disabled all the calls to the application bar and moved everything to OnNavigatedTo but that wasn't the case. I am in the (very long) process of slowly adding bits and pieces of my framework to a new project. This should help me really nail down the culprit.

Comment: I have narrowed it down more. It has to do with the media element, possibly not closing or reopening properly? From testing I know that if Audio is playing/paused at all, the freeze occurs on the reopen

Answer (score 0):

Are you using transitions from the toolkit?
Are they defined in XAML?

If so that could be the issue. There's a bug which is fixed in the next version.
The solution for now is to remove the transitions or define them in code.

Comment: I am using transitions from the toolkit. 
For instance, 
RootFrame = new Microsoft.Phone.Controls.TransitionFrame();

And yes they are defined in xaml, ill see what removing them does right now

Comment: I disabled the transitions and no change. Pivot Selection Change event fires but the screen is still stuck.